# Coverage Warning

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Its a Digit Recognition Coder i am trying to train and test the data and check the accuracy of it

and trying check the LogisticRegression using the data

I am using mnist_784 file to run the code

Question is ,why the given image is not creating in the visual Code I can't get the output that I am accepting

After Runing Code Error:

```
ConvergenceWarning: The max_iter was reached which means the coef_ did not converge
  warnings.warn(
```

for More Under Standing Do run this code Visual Studio:

```
#importing modules here:
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml

#fetching the data:
X,y = fetch_openml("mnist_784",version = 1, return_X_y = True)
print(pd.Series(y).value_counts())
classes = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
nclasses = len(classes)

#Representing the 5 samples:
samples_per_class = 5
figure = plt.figure(figsize = (nclasses*2,(1+samples_per_class*2)))

idx_cls = 0
for cls in classes:
  idxs = np.flatnonzero(y == cls)
  idxs = np.random.choice(idxs, samples_per_class, replace = False)
  i = 0
  for idx in idxs:
    plt_idx = i*nclasses +idx_cls+1
    p = plt.subplot(samples_per_class, nclasses, plt_idx)
    p = sns.heatmap(np.array(X.loc[idx]).reshape(28,28),cmap=plt.cm.gray,
                    xticklabels = True, yticklabels = False, cbar = False)
    p = plt.axis('off')
    i +=1
    idx_cls +=1
    
    idxs = np.flatnonzero(y == '0')
    print(np.array(X.loc[idxs[0]]))
    
    #Fetching out the element from X:
    print(len(X))
    print(len(X.loc[0]))
    
    #Traing and Testing the data:
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state = 9,train_size = 7500, test_size = 2500)
    
    #scaling the features
    X_train_scaled = X_train/255.0
    X_test_scaled = X_test/255.0
    
    print(X.loc[0])
    print(y.loc[0])
    
    #Training the Logistic modul with this data:
    clf = LogisticRegression(solver = 'sag', multi_class = 'multinomial').fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
  
#builting the model:
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_scaled)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
print(accuracy)

#Checking out the confusion matrix:
cm = pd.crosstab(y_test, y_pred, rownames = ['Actual'], colnames = ['Predicted'])

p = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
p = sns.heatmap(cm, annot = True, fmt = 'd',cbar = False)
```

[image]

Comment: What you posted is your setting. You should post your exact issue. Describe it as specific as possible and try to include all relevant, but as little info as possible. Also include what you already tried in order to solve your issue.